# Attempt to call an instance value

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I'm making a game where you ram cars into houses that are made if parts, and when a part at the front of the car hits a `otherPart` the `otherPart` becomes unanchored. I'm trying to make a script where when the `otherPart` becomes unanchored, the player gets + 1 coins, but I keep getting the error above on line 9, any ideas?
code and error
[image: Coding error image]

```
local HitPart = script.Parent
local function onPartTouched(otherPart)
    local Player = otherPart.Parent
    otherPart.Anchored = false
    Player(otherPart.Parent).leaderstats.coins.Value =  Player(otherPart.Parent).leaderstats.coins.Value + 1
end
HitPart.Touched:Connect(onPartTouched)
```

Comment: What do you think `Player(otherPart.Parent)` means?

Comment: You should not post pictures of error messages, instead copy or type the text into the post.

Answer (score 0):

`Player` is an Instance. You cannot call an instance. You can only function values or values with a __call metamethod.

In `Player(otherPart.Parent)` you're attempting to call `Player` which is not allowed.

To get rid of that error remove the two call attempts from your code. You probably wanted to index something else with `leaderstats`